# Under-determined linear system, showing any solution can be written as $x_{0} + Zw$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra

In my notes for under-determined linear systems, the following is just given as fact, but I've restructured it as a question because I don't quite understand it.

> Consider $Ax=b$ where $A$ is an $m \times n$ matrix, $m<n$, $\text{rank}(A) = m$. Let $Z$ be an $n \times (n-m)$ matrix with $\text{rank}(Z) = n-m$ and $AZ = 0_{m \times (n-m)}$. Let $x_{0}$ be any point satisfying $Ax_{0}=b$. Show that every point feasible to $Ax=b$ can be written as $x_{0} + Zw$ for some $w \in \mathbb{R}^{(n-m)}$.

It seems to me like $$A(x_{0} + Zw) = Ax_{0} + AZw = Ax_{0} + 0 = Ax_{0} = b$$
which doesn't really seem to represent any solution, so clearly I'm missing something here.

Comment: You’ve shown the converse: that every point $x_0+Zw$ is a solution to the equation. You need to show that if $x$ and $x_0$ both satisfy the equation, then $x-x_0 \in \operatorname{im}Z$.

Comment: @amd Sorry, I'm not familiar with what you mean by $\text{im}$?

Comment: That stands for the image of a linear transformation, i.e., the space of all possible results of applying its matrix to a vector. In this case, $\operatorname{im}Z=Z\mathbb(R^{n-m})$.

Comment: @amd Ahh I see. So basically all I have to display is $$x-x_{0} = x_{0} + Zw - x_{0} = Zw \in \text{im} \ Z$$ ?

Comment: Almost. You have to show that such a $w$ exists, which it will if you can show that $x-x_0\in\operatorname{im}Z$ some other way.

Comment: @amd And I'm at a loss for how to do so :P I imagine it's some property relating to the fact that $Z$ is an orthonormal basis for the nullspace for $A$.

Comment: That would do it, but you really only need to use the ranks of $A$ and $Z$, as below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ and $x_0$ be solutions of $Ax=b$. Then $A(x-x_0)=Ax-Ax_0=0$, so $x-x_0\in\operatorname{ker}A$. We know from the definition of $Z$ that $\operatorname{im}Z\subseteq\operatorname{ker}A$. However, $\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{im}Z=n-m=\operatorname{dim}\operatorname{ker}A$, so $\operatorname{im}Z=\operatorname{ker}A$. Thus, $x-x_0\in\operatorname{im}Z$ and there is a $w\in\mathbb R^{n-m}$ such that $Zw=x-x_0$.

The quoted statement is a somewhat obscured way of saying that the general solution to the system is the sum of a specific solution and the solution to the homogeneous system $Ax=0$, with the additional twist of $Z$ as an isomorphism between $\mathbb R^{n-m}$ and the solution space of the homogeneous system.